# Facebook publish message to wall with dialog box

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the new SDK FACEBOOK API connect for my iphone application.
With this code my string is direct publish to wall without any dialog box.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"test message",  @"message",
                               nil]; 
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I would like to post a simple string in the wall of user logged with open dialog box, is this possible?

Comment: try using Share kit, it is really simple  and easy to configure

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set his status thought your FB app without showing a dialog you could do it like this

```
NSString *message = @"some text";
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, message,nil];                          
[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self]; //fb here is the FaceBook instance.
```

and for sure you will do that after the user login and authorized the permissions .

To Authorize the permissions

```
if (![fb isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_likes", @"read_stream", nil];
    [fb authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
}
```

**Important :**  If you mean to publish a message with the post dialog actually thats not possible , i faced the same problem and i found this in Facebook documentation

> This field are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling
>   this field erodes the authenticity of the user voice.

Comment: You can update your feed like this, it is possible now. Check out my answer.

Comment: yeah i know you can do it like this .. but the man is asking about to post a have a pre-defined text to show into the textBox which appear in the top of the post dialog , can you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: sorry but not work, dialog box show but message text not appear

Answer (score 0):

You can't prefill the users text area in the dialog, you can only set the message, name, link, image of the prefilled post, but the dialog will add a text area for the user to add additional message, this is not customisable at all.